# How to press div-button by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

Website has the following code:

```
<ul class="left">
    <li><div id="run" class="button"><div class="inner">Run</div></div></li>
</ul>
```

And this script:

```
$("#run").click(function() {...});
```

The following code doesn't work!:(

```
document.getElementById('run').click();
```

How to press the button "Run" by javascript command to browser?

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Do you want to dynamically click the button (without mouse click) or do you want to add a click event to the div?

Comment: The second block of code *was* jQuery; are you actually *using* jQuery, or do the answers need to be in pure/plain/vanilla JavaScript? (If jQuery's acceptable, consider adding the [tag:jquery] tag.)

Comment: jQuery is in the following file: <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>.

I need to run javascript command by browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good old Javascript:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
var run = document.getElementById("run"); 
run.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

In jQuery:

```
$("#run").click();
```

More [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initMouseEvent) aboute firing mouse events manually.

Comment: @Altaveron what was wrong with `$("#run").click();` I can't figure out what was wrong with MДΓΓ БДLL's answer.

Answer (score 6):

Quite simple to do with jQuery  (which it appears that you are already using):

```
$("#run").click();
```

As they say, RTFD: http://api.jquery.com/click.

Comment: @Altaveron define "don't work." What are you trying to accomplish? How about an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), perhaps via http://jsfiddle.net. If you want a better solution, give a better problem description.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$('#run').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Actually it works just as intended, see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jGzGZ/). On the other hand it may not work exactly as you would like it to, wich is probably due to a bad explanation of what your trying to achieve. As for faking a click on a button, this is the way to go, if you are trying to do something else, please explain it a little better.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#run").click(function() { /* ... */ }).trigger('click');
```

Comment: Nope, just trigger a click event anywhere in your script. (after the event has been bound ofc)

Answer (score 0):

Add `onclick="run()"` to the outer div tag.
You may want to add `onselectstart="return false"` to avoid selecting the text.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is asking.